# Difference between Metaphone 3 and Double Metaphone

Tags: nlp, spell-checking, cpu-word, metaphone

I have been reading many articles on Metaphone 3 last couple of days. I saw Metaphone 3 also returns 2 key for each word just like Double Metaphone. Actually, I am confused to figure out what is the core difference between Double Metaphone and Metaphone 3? (Obviously, there is something special about Metaphone 3 since people buying it.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Accuracy: Metaphone 3 is generally considered to be more accurate than Double Metaphone, especially for non-English words and names. Metaphone 3 has a higher precision rate and can handle a wider range of languages and dialects.

2.Output: Metaphone 3 implements settings that cause the algorithm to output keys that more precisely match the pronunciation of the word or name input. However, using these more precise keys for lookup may miss some words or names that could be good matches.

3.Implementation: Metaphone 3 is a more complex algorithm than Double Metaphone and requires more computational resources. It also has more rules and exceptions to handle different languages and dialects. Double Metaphone is a simpler algorithm that can be more easily implemented in programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

Metaphone 3 was developed against a test harness of over a hundred thousand prepared correct encodings and is therefore far more accurate and detailed than any other phonetic encoding algorithm for English by a long shot

Comment: It would be amazing if you could share this test file so we can run these benchmarks ourselves. I know this is a private curated list, but the lack of general usage of Metaphone 3 might improve if it's able to perform.